# Process user-defined partitions of Spark (1.6.1) DataFrames

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` where one column is called `problem_id` and contains a key that identifies a fraction of my entire dataset.

It's not clear to me if `keyBy` + `partitionBy(N)` + `mapPartitions` will divide my dataset into `N=|problem_id|` partitions, in such a way that I can execute some code in parallel on each of my defined partitions.

Otherwise, how could I proceed to achieve this result? 
Basically, my need is to apply one function to all the rows sharing the same `problem_id`. In sparkR there is the `gapply` function, but what's its equivalent in Scala or Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default partitioner (`HashPartitioner`) is a surjection so multiple keys can be hashed to the same partition.

- Direct equivalent of `gapply` in SparkR is `groupBy` followed by `mapValues`.
- If cardinality of the grouping column is reasonably low you can use bijective partitoner:

  ```py
  pmap = rdd.keys().distinct().zipWithIndex().collectAsMap()
  (rdd
      .partitionBy(
          numPartitions=len(parition_map),
          partitionFunc=lambda x: pmap[x])
      .mapPartitions(...))
  ```
- Finally you can `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions`:

  ```py
  (rdd
      .repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions()
      .mapPartitions(...))
  ```

  and keep track of changing keys.